# ¿Cómo limitar alfanumérico de longitud mínima 8 y máxima 150 caracteres en C#?

Tags: c#

```
var name;

if (name >= 8 && name <=100)
{
   Console.Write(name):
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Error");
}
```

Comment: Hola! Sería bueno que modifiques la descripción de tu pregunta y le añadas un contexto, no solo código. Así podrás obtener mejores respuesta. Puedes leer el articulo de cómo preguntar aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: La palabra `var` es una palabra reservada que el compilador ocupa para **inferir** el tipo de dato que la variable contiene. Si pones `var name;` el compilador te marcará un error porque no estás inicializando la variable con **ningún tipo de dato**. Ahora, si escribes, `var name = string.Empty;` el compilador infiere que `name` es de tipo `String`. Ahora, no puedes comparar una cadena con un entero, por lo tanto `name > 8` no tiene sentido; sin embargo, puedes comparar la **longitud** con `name.Length`. Entonces `name.Length>8` **sí** tiene sentido. Con esto puedes completar tu tarea.

Comment: Es una aplicacion escritorio o web?

Comment: Hola, ya lo pude realizar. gracias por tu aportación :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

puedes usar la siguiente expresión regular para validar que sea un valor "alfanumérico de longitud mínima 8 y máxima 150":

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]{8,150}\z(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])
```

Puedes crear un método que indique si el valor es valido o no:

```
private Boolean esValido(string nombre)
{
    string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]{8,150}\z(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])";
    return new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(nombre);
}
```

de esta forma realizarías la validación:

```
if (esValido(name))
{
   Console.Write(name):
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Error");
}
```

Comment: ¿No sería más sencillo `.{8,150}`?

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo valide de otra forma, pero es excelente aportación de código

Answer (score 2):

#### Con expresión regular:

Intenta:

```
^.{8,150}$
```

#### Explicación ☕:

El punto representa todos los caracteres. Excepto \n para lo cual tendrás que usar la bandera s.

#### Else if...

```
string str = "menos de 150 carácteres";
if(str.Length > 8 && str.Length <= 150)
{
    // yeah, tenemos un ganador!!!
}
```

Comment: Excelente aportación !!!

Comment: Gracias, espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Claro que sí, saludos. gracias a ti, por tomarte el tiempo de responder.